# How to create http client in Flutter with token key and use it with Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I want to create http client and I want to use that http client in entire app. Creating http client is not a big deal but I want to add token in header which I get after login.

Right now I'm doing like this:

**web_api_service.dart**

*Here I'm creating http client with dio package with the token after login*

```
class WebApiService{
  final String? tokenKey;
  WebApiService(this.tokenKey);

  Dio _dio = Dio();

  Dio get dio {
    _dio.options.baseUrl = BASE_URL;
    _dio.options.headers = {'token': '$tokenKey'};
    return _dio;
  }

Future<List<SessionData>?> upcomingSessionData(SessionRequest request) async{
    List<SessionData>? sessions;
    try{
      var response = await dio.post('/session/upcommingSession', data: sessionRequestToJson(request));
      final responseMap = response.data;
      // print(responseMap);
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        if(responseMap['status'] == "Success"){
          final data = upcomingSessionFromJson(jsonEncode(responseMap));
          sessions = data.data;
          print(responseMap);
          return sessions;
        }
      }
    } catch (e){
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }
    return sessions;
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

*To get token from Auth I have created a ProxyProvider*

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Auth()),
        ProxyProvider<Auth, WebApiService>(update: (_, auth, __) => WebApiService(auth.tokenKey)),
      ],
      child: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

*Here I'm using FutureBuilder to get the data from api*

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _api = Provider.of<WebApiService>(context, listen: false);
    return FutureBuilder<List<SessionData>?>(
        future: _api.upcomingSessionData(SessionRequest(
            trainerId: "110006",
            lat: "17.387140",
            lng: "78.491684",
            role: "Admin"
        )),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<SessionData>?> snapshot){
          return SomeWidget();
       }
     }
  }
}
```

**What I want?**

- I don't want to use FutureBuilder instead I want to call the api from a controller to separate the UI from business logic.
- I want to create a http client with token key in header (I get token after login) which I can use in entire app.

> Any positive feedback is also appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, I often use injector for it. for example using [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

You can register a singleton to save the token values that you get from authentication logic. let say that we save the token on AuthModel object.
for example:

```
final getIt = GetIt.instance;

class AuthModel {
   String? token;
   AuthModel({this.token});
}

void setup() {
  getIt.registerSingleton<AuthModel>(AuthModel());
}
```

call these setup at main, before everything else is called.

then when we need to update the token, or get the value of these token, just simply call the getIt anywhere in the project.

```
getIt<AuthModel>().token = NEW_TOKEN;
var savedToken = getIt<AuthModel>().token;
```

Comment: Can I create http client as singleton and use getIt there?

Comment: Yes, of course you can also do it.